# Массив объектов. Поиск по переменной объекта

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм, объекты

Для лучшей формулировки приведу сразу код.

```
import os

class A:
    _index = 0
    _value = 0

def findValue(ar,ind):
    l = []
    b = 0
    for i in ar:
        if i._index == ind:
            b += 1
            l.append(i._value)
    if b == 0:
        return []
    else:
        return l

arr = []
for i in range(10):
    tmpA = A()
    tmpA._index = os.urandom(2).encode('hex').upper()
    tmpA._value = os.urandom(32).encode('hex').upper()
    print 'i =',tmpA._index,'v =',tmpA._value
    arr.append(tmpA)
    del tmpA
```

Запускаем, получая массив `arr` (пример случайный):

```
A4CC 0E125E7CE7D1474B9600F50BDF7B03169FF2B7392D3218F30B2403A34ED5E81D
B59B 1ADAE39612D0BD30EAE8D186F2CEED7EA144874EBFD022D850204F748E555D1E
5258 CB004CFCD8BC8A0EC0E6C45119DD70FD859BECDFC367BA9F8294D862ED07585D
63DF FB12F4020BE62351C6F87BA170CA1A945AEFF6C1DA12B0C8F4356F0CDC6729A4
2FF4 2B44AE2E462361FEFEE5251275F4329A327B8D2CCE24C0A2A1BB3E95E522B217
A2EF B8DC1FD47FB12A1AF74F44B2176F3B508A9748183E49FD1E4474027FE6DD39F9
ADBE 442C12FD91FAB2EA668CAD336EF5F7B97D3953E7362DCDE50C74D965CB86BE59
581D FE47CBE6A3F91F020C531A568F5D047CEABD0B95C00933370B59D4B126336555
D572 FED36C1198DDE66A62B40DF90529EEFD2AD3F5298490D84FFD4DBA5CEE5A16C8
EBFE 4A6511059AB17DF2FC4432260C527885760233527D9CF6349AA307DF2BB80F48
```

Далее, вызываем функцию `findValue`:

```
findValue(arr,'2FF4')
```

Получаем:

```
['2B44AE2E462361FEFEE5251275F4329A327B8D2CCE24C0A2A1BB3E95E522B217']
```

Вопрос. Как реализовать функцию `findValue` оптимальным способом, т.е. без перебора массива `arr`? Можно ли как-то обращаться по `_index`?

То есть интересует способ, который будет быстрее. Спасибо

Comment: Есть какие-то причины не использовать словарь?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за подсказку

Используя словарь, работает чуть быстрее.

```
import os

def findValue(ar,s):
    return ar[s]

arr = {}
for i in range(10):
    iA = os.urandom(2).encode('hex').upper()
    iB = os.urandom(32).encode('hex').upper()
    arr[iA] = iB
    print iA,iB
```

Comment: Если только в вашей реальной задаче не возникнет ситуации повторяющегося `iA`.

Comment: Как в этом случае обрабатывать исключение, когда `arr[iA]` отсутствует?

Comment: Верное замечание. Вы можете ответить на вопрос от себя?

Comment: Ну это уже не имеет прямого отношения к исходному вопросу, поэтому в ответ не вижу смысла выносить. Используйте `ar.get(s)`. В случае отсутствия значения по ключу не будет выброшено исключение, функция вернет `None`.